# how to share an ' .app ' (created with py2app) from Mac to iPhone?

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2app

I've created a Mac app and I'd like to share it to my iPhone and run it there, but when I share it via mail or airdrop, I can't open it.

Comment: Have you installed a Python app like this? - http://omz-software.com/pythonista/

Comment: @DaveS No, why? When I share it to my phone, I can't open the file...

Comment: You cannot run mac apps on phones. Note that your mac runs `OS X` as an operating system. The iphone runs `iOS`. They are mutually incompatable at a fundamental level.That said, [pythonista](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pythonista-3/id1085978097?mt=8) can let you run and modify a `.py` file, but a `.app` file is never going to work because phones just don't work that way. An iphone physically cannot run a computer application.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy okay, thanks, but is there a way I can make a app for my iPhone with my Mac?

Comment: Yes, check out [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), the Apple proprietary development IDE for creating apps for both mac and iphone. Or google "iphone app development" and look at some of the "where do I start" tutorials.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy is that also with python? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can't run a MacOS application on IOS. Instead, remake it with for example `Xcode` so the application can run on your iPhone.